# Python working with dictionary, files

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

I have this code:

```
def merge_new_old_urls(urls_list, urls_file_path):
    url_dict = {}
    try:
        with open(urls_file_path, "r") as f:
            data = f.readlines()
        for line in data:
            #read what is already in file
            url_dict = { line.split()[0]: int(line.split()[1])}
        for new in urls_list:
            for key in url_dict.keys():
                if new == key:
                    print 'found'
                    url_dict[key] += 1
                else:
                    url_dict[new] = 1

    except IOError:
        logging.critical('no files to read from %s' % urls_file_path)
        raise IOError('no files to read from %s' % urls_file_path)
    return url_dict
```

This should read data from file and merge it with new list of data, counting how many times it was repeated. File with old urls looks like this:

```
http://aaa.com 1
http://bbb.com 2
http://ccc.com 1
```

if the new list of url contains http://aaa.com http://bbb.com the dict should be:

```
'http://aaa.com':2
'http://bbb.com':3
'http://ccc.com':1
```

But my code doesn't work right. Can someone healp ?

Comment: But my code doesn't work right...What is wrong??????

Comment: Please define "doesn't work right". Is it producing the wrong output, no output, an exception, ...

Comment: Why are you comparing all the keys in a dictionary? Might dictionary have a quick look up method?

Comment: it prints that everything repeated 1 time only

Comment: I understand the first two lines of output but the third is different

Comment: `cat file1 file2 | sort | uniq -c`. Amazing that, after decades, people are still trying to reinvent basic unix tools

Comment: as the third wasn't new, but it was in old file it mustn't change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You redefine `url_dict` each time through the loop:

```
url_dict = {line.split()[0]: int(line.split()[1])}
```

Add the entries to the dictionary instead:

```
for line in data:
    key, val = line.split()
    if key in url_dict:
        url_dict[key] += val
    else:
        url_dict[key] = val
```

And your search through the dictionary is completely unnecessary, you can use the same syntax as above:

```
for key in urls_list:
    if key in url_dict:
        url_dict[key] += val
    else:
        url_dict[key] = val
```

Finally, you shouldn't wrap so much in a `try`:

```
try:
   with open(urls_file_path, "r") as f:
        data = f.readlines()
except IOError:
    logging.critical('no files to read from %s' % urls_file_path)
    raise IOError('no files to read from %s' % urls_file_path)
else:
    # rest of your code
```